# EasyMock Not making a distinction between subclasses

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

Given the following

```
class Event{
}

class SpecialEvent extends Event{

}

class OtherEvent extends Event{

}

class EventPublisher{
   public publish(Event e){
   }
}

@test
testBlah{
   myService = new MyService();

   mockEvent = createMock(EventPublisher)
   mySercice.setEventPublisher(mockEvent);
   mockEvent.publish(anyObject(SpecialEvent.class));
   expectLastCall.once();
   replay(mockEvent);
   myServce.doSomethingThatCauesesSpecialEventToBePublished();
   verify(mockEvent);
}
```

If myService.doSomething.... Publishes an event that is NOT SpecialEvent.class it does not fail the test as long as the event extends from Event. Is there a way to ensure that this fails?

Comment: Please check the code you posted. It seems to have random braces and missing semicolons. Very hard to see what the problem might be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`anyObject` will match *any object* - the class just changes the return type. I suspect you want `isA`:

```
mockEvent.publish(isA(SpecialEvent.class));
```

Comment: Ahh thanks I was assuming that it meant - Any object of type X and if an object that was not of type X was passed in, it would fail.